# Get Active Subwindow

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-3.5

I want to check in an foreign application if a defined subwindow is opened and in foreground.

If I check it using winapi [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx) I get the handle of the main window, instead of the actual active subwindow.

I can enumerate with winapi [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) through all windows matching the title, but this will only provide the information, that the subwindow is open, but not if it is in foreground.

Howto merge both things?

Comment: By [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx), the active window is always a top-level window (just like the foreground window). *"The actual active subwindow"* is not something that exists. What are you really looking for? Besides, this sounds like an XY question. Why do you need to know? Are you trying to implement some sort of brittle UI automation?

Comment: I don't see how this information is helpful in solving the question, but here you go:
There is an old com-application where I'm not allowed to change a bit. That's why I need to trace some input in a defined control.

Comment: The information is useful in improving your question. As written, it is asking for something that doesn't exist. The information is also useful, since it helps us to keep you from implementing a car with square wheels. If you want to observe/automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). With UI Automation you don't need what you intended to ask for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the foreground window with `GetForegroundWindow`.
2. Find the thread that owns that window with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`.
3. Find the GUI info (active window, focus window, capture window etc.) for that thread with `GetGUIThreadInfo`.

Comment: Did it slightly different. I used `EnumWindows` with my desired window title and called `GetWindowThreadProcessId` for all resulting handles checking for equality to `GetWindowThreadProcessId` of `GetForegroundWindow`.